# Is it possible to provide intellisense for dynamic objects in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, intellisense

I am using dynamic objects in a project, and I'd like to provide intellisense for the object. I understand that Visual Studio can't know what to show for intellisense, but if I can plug into the intellisense, I do know what entries should show up.

Is there a way to extend Visual Studio's intellisense? If so, any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Editor Extension Points.

You can find specific information for extending Intellisense near the bottom of this page:

[Editor Extension Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd885244%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

From this page you can get information about [ICompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.icompletionsource%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [ICompletionSourceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.icompletionsourceprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which are the two interfaces you must implement to provide autocompletion.