# Create Intellisense from stored dynamic objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, dynamic, intellisense

Im about to create some settings for MVC projects and sites, based on dynamic variables etc.
These settings will be stored in xml for easy read and write.

My question now, after reading about extending the intellisense in this question:

[Is it possible to provide intellisense for dynamic objects in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645630/is-it-possible-to-provide-intellisense-for-dynamic-objects-in-visual-studio)

Is if its possible to read my saved settings (which are stored at runtime) and then for the next run build a intellisense from that?

I.E. for each of these `site.setings.layout.width` a list of the "older" saved xml-defined defined dynamics will be able to show up?

Comment: You should check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645630/is-it-possible-to-provide-intellisense-for-dynamic-objects-in-visual-studio

Comment: @OP - i presume the -1 to my answer comes from you. You could consider editing your question to be more specific and clear instead of downvoting people that are just trying to be helpful.

Comment: @AZ. in fact no, i just upvoted it to 0, so no idea who would downvote it :S

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is xml "intellisense" then consider designing xml schemas and dump them in `Visual Studio installation Folder\xml\Schemas` or include them in your solution and VS will do the rest if the namespaces match appropriately.

Edit:
Coming back to this after a while. No other answer appears to have been given so I'll try to be more creative.

1. Visual Studio has an option to generate an xsd from an xml file. Note that the schema will be mostly an approximation but it will match the file and will be a good description of structure. If you could find a way to call that from a command line (or possibly find a similar tool for the step) you can then chain that with xsd.exe and generate C# classes from it at build time (prebuild step)
2. If point one is too cumbersome you could try to write a [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx) that reads a previous configuration file and generates your custom code based on that. Generating a POCO property structure based on some xml should be fairly simple with T4. The template should be run as a precompiled step.

Note that both suggestions involve static code generation. A full dynamic solution could be done with [F# type providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509.aspx) but that is not available for C#.

Comment: Will this give intellisense on the xml you mean?
Or will it actually pick up when i write for example
`site.setings.layout.width` for each step if there is xmls for it?

Comment: on the actual xml. it won't help you in your dynamic code. maybe i misunderstood the question