# How to implement Intellisense to a Dynamic class in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I'm trying to find a way to create a Dynamic Class with Intellisense. I have tried to follow the same instructions in this post [Is it possible to provide intellisense for dynamic objects in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645630/is-it-possible-to-provide-intellisense-for-dynamic-objects-in-visual-studio), perhaps I didn't succeed to do it. Impossible to implements the two Interfaces `ICompletionSource` and `ICompletionSourceBuilder`, they're unrecognized by Visual Studio version 2015.`

Bellow my code for the moment :

```
namespace IntellisenseTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic d = new DynamicDictionary();
            d.test = "test";
            Console.WriteLine(d.test);
            Console.Read();
        }

    }


    internal class DynamicDictionary :  DynamicObject
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dictionary
        = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public override bool TryGetMember(
        GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            string name = binder.Name.ToLower();

            return dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result);
        }

        public override bool TrySetMember(
        SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {
            dictionary[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Impossible to implements the two Interfaces ICompletionSource and ICompletionSourceBuilder, they're unrecognized by Visual Studio version 2015.`

Because these two Interfaces ICompletionSource and ICompletionSourceBuilder belong to visual studio, you need to install visual studio SDK before you use the two interfaces  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683786.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Here is a sample about the usage ICompletionSource  for your reference. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've forgotten to install the sdk. But it still doesn't working, I installed the sdk then restart my pc and the two Interfaces still longer unrecognized. I've seen in your second link `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense;`, and it's also unknow by VisualStudio.

Comment: Please Add the following references to the project and make sure that CopyLocal is set to false  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense

Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop

Comment: Ahh sorry I missed it, so now I don't really now how to add Intellisense to my Dynamic Class with these two Interfaces. Altough is it possible to do that to a Dynamic Class?